# Laravel Session Returns NULL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

My Laravel 5.5 instance is working fine on localhost, however, when I upload it to the server, sessions don't work. I've set the session driver to the database, and I can see data stored in the database.

[image]

The problem is reading sessions which always return null.

```php
function index(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->input('set_sess')) {
        try {
            $request->session()->put('test', 'xxx');
            $request->session()->save();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            dd($e->getMessage());
        }
        dd('session was set');
    }

    if ($request->input('get_sess')) {
        dd($request->session()->get('test'));
    }
}
```

**session.php**

```
'driver' => env('SESSION_DRIVER', 'database'),
'encrypt' => false,
'connection' => 'mysql',
'table' => 'sessions',
'domain' => 'example.com',
'secure' => false,
```

**.env**

```
APP_NAME=examplename
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://example.com

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=database
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

Comment: can you not just simply use 
session(['key', 'value']);
session('key)

Comment: Can you try changing `'secure' => true` to `'secure' => false` in your `session.php` config since you don't have HTTPS.

Comment: @Remul i tried "false" but it didnt work.

Comment: can you run `php artisan config:clear` after changing the value.

Answer (score 1):

Try this please:
(You dont need `->save()`)

replace:

```
$request->session()->put('test', 'xxx');
$request->session()->save();
```

with:

```
session()->put('test', 'xxx');
```

Comment: didnt make any difference.